# Unable to mock a class that has super method

Tags: python, python-mock

## test.py

```
import mock

@mock.patch('google.cloud.spanner_v1.client.Client')
def test_read_with_query(self, mock_client_class):
    mock_client = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_client_class.return_value = mock_client
    ...
```

## module.py

```
from google.cloud.spanner import Client

def method_to_test(self):

    spanner_client = Client(self._project_id)
    print spanner_client
    exit()
```

I am trying to mock this client class but receiving following error

> TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not MagicMock

Basiclly the Client class has a call to `super(Client)` it its constructor that is crashing.

I know in PHP we had a option to `disableConstructor()` in `PHPUnit`.

Looking forward to some work aroung to by pass this constructor thing or any other pythonic way

Thanks